# Help doing or Help to do or Help in doing

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> ... I am sure you don't need any ***help coming*** up with new ideas.
>   (It is from a tv-series. A is saying this to B ironically because B
>   keeps coming up with absurd ideas all the time.)

Is this sentence grammatical as is? or Should it be rewritten as in:

> I am sure you don't need any ***help in coming*** up with new ideas.
>
> I am sure you don't need any ***help to come*** up with new ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Someone may disagree with one or other of the three sentences, but all of them are acceptable in idiomatic English. All 3 versions get well over one million hits each if you Google them.

Comment: Note that Google Web Search isn't a curated English corpus, and the number of results it reports is an estimate (which is often quite off). For that, try [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/). (It's pretty easy to use.)

Comment: @userr2684291 point taken, I wasn't aware of that site and I agree that Google counts are not accurate. Using  the COCA,  the British National corpus and the iWeb data bases all 3 phrases are, very approximately, equally represented.